# How to write not field name but verbose name of field in this code?

Tags: python, django

How to write not field name but verbose name of field (in column title) in this code (Export to xls) ?

```
def export_as_xls(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        raise PermissionDenied
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta

    wb = Workbook()
    ws0 = wb.add_sheet('0')
    col = 0
    field_names = []
    # write header row
    for field in opts.fields:
        ws0.write(0, col, field.name)
        field_names.append(field.name)
        col = col + 1

    row = 1
    # Write data rows
    for obj in queryset:
        col = 0
        for field in field_names:
            val = unicode(getattr(obj, field)).strip()
            ws0.write(row, col, val)
            col = col + 1
        row = row + 1   

    f = StringIO()
    wb.save(f)
    f.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(f.read(), mimetype='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.xls' % unicode(opts).replace('.', '_')
    return response

export_as_xls.short_description = "Export selected objects to XLS"
```

I see `field.name` but I don't know how to change it. This code is from django snippet site

Comment: What happens when you swap all occurrences of `field.name` with `field.verbose_name`?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting the question, but if you want to change field.name:

```
for field in opts.fields:
    field.name = 'Foo'
```

This would change all the field names to "Foo"